# Inplace enumeration

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and ruby on rails 3.x . I have many lines like this

```
lines = lines.map {|e| e.strip}
lines = lines.map {|e| e.upcase}
lines = lines.map {|e| sanitize_element(e)}
```

Rather than assigning new values to lines every time is there a better way to handle this. I know I can do

```
lines = lines.map {|e| sanitize_element(e.strip.upcase) }
```

but that is not the main point of this question. The main thing is to find if there is a way to handle the above case without assigning value to lines every time.

Basically I am looking for a solution as elegant as this, but I know there isn't a `map!` in Enumerable.

```
lines.map! {|e| e.strip}
```

Just making sure that I am not missing out on a ruby feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using `Array#map!`:

```
lines.map! { |e| e.strip }
lines.map! { |e| e.upcase}
# ...
```

Often, an immutable method like `map` is paired with a dangerous one like `map!`, which causes the receiver to be modified. I recommend against using these, since half the point of nice, functional-style enumerable programming is to get the benefits of immutability (referential transparency, etc.). But if you're going to reassign on each enumeration, you might as well use `map!`.

Comment: map! is not listed at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001491 . Let me try it.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually on `Array`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000250; I think that the reason for this is the `Enumerable` only specifies immutable ways of doing things.

Comment: Which makes sense, as `Enumerable` is only a module - it doesn't even know what class it's getting mixed into.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could write

```
lines = lines.map {|e| e.strip}.map {|e| e.upcase}.map {|e| sanitize_element(e)}
```

in a fluent fashion. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

In case if `sanitize_element!` exists you can try this way:

```
lines.map! do |e|
  e.strip
  e.upcase
  e.sanitize_element
end
```

I think it looks more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For interest, note that you could leave the array alone and concentrate on modifying the strings themselves. Like this:

```
lines.each do |e|
  e.strip!
  e.upcase!
  e.replace(e.sanitize_element)
end
```

In a quick benchmark on random data this looked like it ran in about 2/3rds the time of the multiple-`map!` version, although obviously you'd want to verify this on your actual data and operations.